# Why enabled is not exposed as xml attribute in Android View

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml

I know that there are few properties for which attributes are not present is xml but there is java code to use those properties, though I never understood the reason for those, but for enabled it seems really strange to me for following reasons

1. TextView and its subclasses exposes it in xml
2. Layer list also has states as state_enabled and which is too exposed in xml, also you can set layer-list drawable on any xml.

So why not enabled is exposed as an attribute? Is there a particular reason for it or its just based on the api designer's choice which I guess should not be the case